# Is there any emulator for Huawei p30

Tags: android, testing, emulation, huawei-mobile-services

I have an android app which is working fine on Samsung, Google, Asus devices.

But it is not working only for Huawei P30 devices, I want to test the app on **Huawei devices**, Is there any emulator for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this amazing website:

https://www.pcloudy.com/

You can test Huawei devices in online. It's free for 30 mins.

Comment: devices i want to test are paid..

Comment: almost all the devices are paid.

Answer (score 7):

## Short answer

Yes, you can find it and use it on Huawei developer account in section Cloud Debugging.

## Longer answer

Once you create account on https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/ (top right corner - `Console`), you will be able try out Cloud Debugging.

[image]

Cloud Debugging is a platform to test out you application on physical Huawei devices from cloud platform. It is free and it is working pretty fast.

[image]

Comment: Hi @deadfish. Your screenshot shows many devices including the one i want to test on. But I can only see the P40 series and Mate 30 series. Is there some setting I need to enable to see the rest or did Huawei remove the rest of the devices?

Comment: Asia has the biggest amount of devices for testing. Europe has big amount of devices for testing. Rest of regions might have less amount of devices. Try to use account registered in Europe.

Comment: It all depends on account type and ip used to register your account. You can also try to check out devices from Android Studio by installing this plugin: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/

Comment: Cloud debugging is fine until you need some advanced tools (which are not available in Guest mode on devices). like developer options, mock location, etc :)